# Windows use Mac windows keyboard shortcuts

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I use at home Mac with czech keyboard. In work we have to use Windows 10. Is it possible remap windows keyboard shortcuts like shortcuts on Mac? For example Right  Alt + 9 = { or semicolon etc.
Thank you for response

Comment: You probably want to have a look at [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com).

Comment: Isn't the actual key more of a shortcut than an alt combination?  That seems like a "longcut".